# How to access a variable after it is getting defined by the ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

How can I access `inner_variable` after it is getting defined by the ajax call?

PS: I can't change anything in the ajax call `success` callback.
I tried to use `setTimeout` but it's not efficient enough.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   inner_variable = inner_variable + 1;


   jQuery.ajax({
         //code

   }).done(function(response){
     var inner_varaiable  = response;
   });


});
```

Comment: Use callback functions.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: If I understand your problem, you are trying to access the value assigned in your ajax done from outside of ajax?

Comment: @dbarnes
Well, the code is much complicated. The ajax call is in another js file which I can't change anything in it. That variable contains (Maps Markers) and I want to change the popup text of the markers.

Comment: You **can** access the variable, from inside the `.done()` callback.

Comment: @Pointy I think he wants to access it outside of that.

Comment: I still don't understand, are you trying to call some function after the ajax completes or are you trying to call something right after the ajax call is executed? As Script47 explains the code to execute done doesn't happen till later

Comment: @Pointy I mentioned in the question that I don't have access to the `done()` function.

Comment: No, you said you don't have access to the "success" callback. In any case, if you can't touch that code, there's really nothing you can do other than use a hack like a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback function like below, you then use `response` by passing it through to the `callback`.

```
function myAjaxFunction (myCallback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
         //code

    }).done(function(response){
         myCallback(response);
   });   
}

myAjaxFunction(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    // Then you can use response.
});
```

Because **A**JAX is `asynchronous` you can't do it like you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change anything in the success callback, you could hook onto the ajaxComplete callback and put your setTimeout there.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // setTimeout or setInterval after a short delay to check inner_variable till it's defined 
});
```

Comment: How can I hook into XmlHttpRequest object?

Comment: Thank you anyway, I used this library to hook into XmlHttpRequest objects 
https://github.com/jpillora/xhook

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look about scopes.
I mean if you do :

```
   var myvalue; /*value undefined this scope is private */function test (){myvalue = 'foo'/*
This will overwrite myvalue outher context inside function myvalue produces foo */} //myvalue out the function is foo
```

When you declare var the context is private to the scope if you declare without var means the global scope and you can overwrite 
Hope you help